# Is it bad to use a CSS class as part of the programming logic to implement business rules?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple `DIV` items on the page that users can select, and what I have implemented in my JavaScript code is that when an item was selected, I added a CSS class to it to flag that it is a selected item and then later use it to apply business rules logic around it.

That was just an example, but in general however, I am wondering if I should be using the class in this way, as the class itself does not change the presentation of the page in any way, and the intention of CSS classes were for presentation purposes. Is doing it this way a case of mixing presentation and business logic, which is considered not a good design pattern?

Furthermore, it might trigger the browser to perform some presentation processing overhead when the class is added and possibly slow things down.

I was wondering if what I should be doing instead is adding state information as a custom attribute to the `DOM` element?

Comment: There is no such thing as "a CSS class". Classes are part of HTML, not CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what happens when you add a class to a element, I can't find any information on that right now, but I would expect some work to be done behind the scenes to check that there isn't any styles associated with that specific class so I wouldn't recommend doing it as it would make no sense because that is what the `data-*` attribute was designed for.

I'm sure it would also be more syntactical to use the `data-*` attribute to store data than it would to use a class.

So you have 2 choices that are.

Use a `class` that is designed for applying **styles** to an element and may also run some unnecessary code in the background to check for styles.

Or use a `data-*` attribute that was designed to store this type of data on a specific element and will probably not run any unnecessary code in the background.

I know for sure that I would choose option 2.

**Update**

You may see some javascript frameworks that use some data in classes that don't actually apply any styles, an example would be angular.js, they use `ng-binding` & `ng-scope` classes. But I'm pretty sure the only reason that they use a class for this data is so they can get all of the elements with the class using `getElementsByClassName`.

You can also use a javascript object to keep track of this kind of stuff, Here is an example that keeps track of what elements have been clicked.

```
var clickedElements = [];
forEach -- allElements -- .addEventListener('click', function() {
   clickedElements.push(this);
});
// ^ Here you would actually have to loop through the elements
// To apply the event Listener.
```

This way you can just loop through all of the elements easily and it doesn't effect your DOM stuff.

Here is a tiny part of a article read not that long ago.

> Have you ever found yourself using element class names or rel attributes to store arbitrary snippets of metadata for the sole purpose of making your JavaScript simpler? If you have, then I have some exciting news for you! **If you haven't and you're thinking, Wow, that's a great idea! I implore you to rid your mind of that thought immediately and continue reading**.

**Source: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/**

Answer (score 5):

In general it is not wrong to do so. Frameworks like jQuery are amongst other things built around the use of class attributes.

However, as of HTML5 there is a more elegant solution for most cases, which is the so called data properties.

This allows you to add any arbitrary property to your HTML tag if you prefix it with `data-`.

An example would be:

```
<div data-value="3">Amount: $3.00</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

no, this is just fine. Classes these days are not just used for CSS styling, but also to indicate the behavioural role an element plays. If you use a class "selected" to indicate that a normally not-selectable element is currently the user's element of choice, that's pretty much in line with what everyone else is doing on the web right now.

As long as you make sure to name-space your classes so it doesn't conflict with external JS libraries that rely on the same generic name of course. "selected" is a horrible name and likely to conflict with a million libraries. "xol-ui-selected", on the other hand, would be pretty solid.

Comment: Is it good to do *What everyone else is doing on the web right now*? It's hard to stand out from the crowd, but it's almost always a good choice.

Comment: take a random guess how standards come about (but the hint is "because everyone is doing this" =). Using classes to indicate UX behavioural roles is currently a standard practice.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to end this convo now :), but I will say, I won't do something because everyone else is doing it.

Comment: Classes never were just for styling, that's just what they were primarily used for.

Comment: @RobG What else would they have been used for?

Comment: @Pinocchio: in HTML 4 the class attribute is to be used as "As a style sheet selector" as well as "For general purpose processing by user agents" (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2), in HTML 5 even those loose 'restrictions' on what they were supposed to be for have been removed (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes)

Answer (score 2):

The underlying issue is storing data in the DOM instead of a JavaScript data structure. For your implementation, it's probably not a bad idea. The performance loss will be negligible, so there isn't much justification to using JavaScript data structures like arrays or objects.

Now imagine you're building a spreadsheet application with 1000 rows and 30 columns. Querying the DOM every time a cell is changed will make your application feel sluggish, so obviously you need to come up with a better approach.

So to answer your question: no, it's not okay, but it probably doesn't matter. The better solution would be to separate your presentation from your business logic and make changes to the DOM in response to changes to the underlying JavaScript objects.